# Run Neo4j queries stored in excel workbook in python (Jupyter)

Tags: python, neo4j, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an excel worksheet which contains Neo4j cypher queries and I would like to load the excel file into python to run the queries instead of running them manually.

is there a special library that does this? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

neo4j library has the function to do this.

```py
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
graphdb=GraphDatabase.driver(uri="$uri",auth=("$user","$password"))
session=graphdb.session()
session.run("Your query goes here")
graphdb.close()
```

This only will run the command, is up to you what you'll do with the info you get.

More info about this topic here:
https://neo4j.com/developer/python/
https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/transactions.html